# Can I use a Mac Mini with VS 2015 for Cross Platform Development?

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms

I am gearing up to build a Xamarin based universal app. It appears I need to have a Mac to deploy and test against an iPhone, if I am reading things correctly, as there is no emulator available. As it appears that I am using the Mac as basically a router, can I use a Mac Mini? Is the 1.4 GHz enough or do I need a 2.6+ GHz model? I really don't have the desk space for a full Mac.

Comment: You can, if you use it as remote build host (1,4 might be a bit slow as a full blown dev machine). We are using mac mini as buildserver.

Comment: Is putting a dev machine *under* the desk out of fashion?

Comment: Please don't ask for hardware recommendations.  They're off topic on SO.

Comment: @Jason generally I would agree, but this is more of a specific edge case imposed by closed Apple architecture than a simple "is this machine good?". Its probably in the first 5 questions anyone using Xamarin is going to have.

Answer (score 3):

You don't only need the Mac for access to an emulator - you also need it for the actual compilation/linking. The Apple SDK is required for producing binaries that will run on an iOS device.

Another consideration: you will need to be running either the Business or Enterprise tier of Xamarin in order to use the iOS Build Server feature.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a Mac to run the simulator, yes. As a Forms-based iOS application  still effectively starts a Xamarin.iOS project, you can use a guide such as the one [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/installation/windows/introduction_to_xamarin_ios_for_visual_studio/) to get started with deploying to an iOS simulator running on a Mac with Visual Studio. As for the power of the machine, a 1.4Ghz model will be fine as long as you're running El Capitan for the current version of Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Word of advice... Get a Mac Mini that supports at least Sierra OS. This means that you will need a Mac Mini >= mid 2010.